# Can you make a property and populate with values on the fly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the JavaScript library d3.  My data is in a csv file and I'm able to access and graph the data values by any of the existing property values (such as `d.a` or `d.b`).  However, I'd like to create a new property value from the existing values.  For example, if the following is my dataset:

```
name,a,b
Jim,72,66
Jim,74,49
Jim,79,50
Sarah,48,23
Sarah,54,28
Sarah,43,22
```

Without having to hardcode values into the csv file, when my code is called, I'd like to (for example) create a new property called `product` that has values computed as `a*b` for each record and I'd like to be able to access the new property in my code by name as `d.product`.

How could I go about doing so, if this even is possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
   d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.product = +d.a * +d.b;
        })
    })
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do and it works perfectly. Thanks! Marked as answer and +1.